# Modifying a RecievePayment with QB Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

When I modify a payment using the RecievePaymentMod request, I need to supply the txnID of the payment.  Then in the response, it sends back a txnID (don't know if it's the same or not, haven't put it into practice yet).

If I have to modify the same payment again, do I use the txnID returned from the original ReceivePaymentAdd request, or the txnID returned from the last RecievePaymentMod request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> don't know if it's the same or not, haven't put it into practice yet

It is.

The TxnID is a unique primary key for QuickBooks, just like your unique primary key in any standard database system.

> If I have to modify the same payment again, do I use the txnID returned from the original ReceivePaymentAdd request, or the txnID returned from the last RecievePaymentMod request?

It's the same value. It's a unique key that never changes.